# What is Pluton and its relation with the Void Century?

Tags: one-piece

What exactly is Pluton and regarding that, what is so special about the Void Century?

Comment: [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Pluton) has an article about it, and I'm not sure how much you know about Pluton before we can answer it without copypasting the whole Wikia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pluton is one of the 3 Ancient Weapons capable of mass destruction. The other 2 are Poseidon (currently **Shirahoshi**) and the ancient ship, **Pluton**.

Uranus is not shown yet but if *speculations are to be considered*, it is said that it is a giant machine that can eradicate a single country.

Void Century as its name implies, a `century` that is hidden by the World Government to the public. It is a century where the 20 kingdoms fought against the "D" and won. After the War, they've joined together and formed the World Government as their acting police and their descendants are the Celestial Dragons. The only exception was the Nefertari family who refused to join them in *Mariejois*, the holy land of the Celestial Dragons.

Not much is known what happened during the void century because it is clouded in mystery. Only a few people are known to have knowledge about it, including the Ohara people where Robin came from, and Roger himself.

It is heavily implied that the Void Century, **D**, and Poneglyphs are heavily connected.

Comment: Thanks @Shan Coralde. This makes things pretty clear and now even more interesting.

Comment: You're welcome. A simple wiki/google visit would help too.

Comment: You confuse Uranus with Pluton. Pluton is the ship which blueprints were destroyed by Franky, Uranus is yet to be unkown.

Comment: @xhadon Fixed it.